# iOS Swift/Obj-C Framework, Test Target doesn't load Swift Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xctest

I have an app target consisting of four self written frameworks. Each of this frameworks consists out of Swift as well as Obj-C code. So far so good.

Currently only the application target has the build option "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" set to yes. Therefore the frameworks test targets fail to run with the following error

```
The test bundle at
/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeProject
gbkzuhubemghuoeuebqsuphggisv/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/SomeFrameworkTests.xctest could not be loaded because an
unanticipated error occurred.
2015-07-10 15:36:55.402 xctest[24678:1813940] Detailed error 
information: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle 
“SomeFrameworkTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing 
necessary resources." 
(dlopen_preflight(/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeProject-
gbkzuhubemghuoeuebqsuphggisv/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/SomeFrameworkTests.xctest/SomeFrameworkTests): Library not loaded: 
@rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
```

I can fix this by setting the build option "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" for all frameworks to yes. But in this case I include the swift runtime five times in the final ipa. This means a size increase of more than 100% (14mb vs. 6mb - with the runtime only included once).

Enabling the build option "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" only for the frameworks test target does not fix the problem. Sigh.

Do you have any idea on how to run the test targets with embedded Swift Runtime, but not compile the Runtime into the Release Build?

Comment: What happens if you add a test case class written in Swift to the test target?